# What is the motivation for excellent rings?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

First of all I am not formally educated in mathematics so pardon my ignorance if this is obvious and I am skipping something vital, but I am interested nonetheless in what the original motivation and applications are for excellent rings and by extension quasi-excellent rings conceptually. I know they were first described by Grothendieck in effort to describe phenomena with the resolutions of singularities, but I can't seem to find any specific conceptual applications they have. Every time I've tried researching this I get the definition of them without any further elaboration of why they are defined the way they are.  If someone could describe their specific uses or provide a source to do so that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: There are people more qualified to answer, so I'll just drop a comment, but my impression is that quasiexcellent rings are considered because they are known to be the largest class of (Noetherian) rings/schemes over which resolution of singularities is possible - as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excellent_ring#Resolution_of_singularities) mentions, if we can resolve singularities of all finite algebras over a ring, it is quasiexcellent (and the proof is not that complicated). Excellence then adds a "stability" condition on top of it, so finite type algebras behave well too.

Comment: I have never worked with excellent rings so take this comment with a grain of salt, but I believe the main point is to block weird counterexamples and allow you to argue the way your geometric intuition says you "ought" to be able to argue. For comparison, why assume a ring is regular? It's not always because the hypothesis is strictly necessary; sometimes it's so we don't have to worry about some pathology sneaking in and breaking the proof. I think of "excellent" as a stronger version of "regular" that is preserved under a bunch of common operations that may not preserve regularity.

Answer (score 5):

(As the name suggests,) (quasi-)excellent rings are rings that are very well-behaved under various natural operations: localisation, finite type extension, formal completion (some hypothesis here), henselisation. One may well imagine that Grothendieck was looking for a property permanent under these operations. Excellent integral domains are also universally Japanese, which may be useful to know.

The first non-trivial example of an excellent ring is that of a complete noetherian local ring. The formal completion $\widehat{A}$ of a local ring $A$ may not inherit some properties of $A$, like reduceness or normality; it does when $A$ is excellent.

Now, my familiarity with excellent rings is rather superficial and I can never remember all the things that go into defining them. My go to place is Exposé I in [Travaux de Gabber](http:////http://fabrice.orgogozo.perso.math.cnrs.fr/travaux_de_Gabber/). There, in 2.11, Raynaud briefly mentions the link with the resolution of singularities: every characteristic zero quasi-excellent scheme $X$ admits a desingularisation à la Hironaka; conversely, if every integral scheme $Y$ finite over $X$ admits a resolution of singularities, then $X$ is quasi-excellent.

Comment: Excellent reference, here is the corrected link: [Travaux de Gabber](http://fabrice.orgogozo.perso.math.cnrs.fr/travaux_de_Gabber/01-quasi-excellents/excellent.pdf).

Comment: @abx Thank you.